# ListFragment con primer ítem detallado

Tags: android, android-layout, lista, arrayadapter

Estoy tratando de programar un **ListFragment** con una vista como esta:

[image: List con item detallado]

En la cual el primer item tiene un **layout** diferente, segun con lo que he leido con este codigo deberia funcionar, pero se detiene

Codigo Adapter:

```
public class NotificacionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_COUNT = 2;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_DETAIL = 0;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL = 1;

public NotificacionAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Notificacion> notificaciones) {
    super(activity,0, notificaciones);
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Notificacion notificacion = (Notificacion)getItem(position);






    // Choose the layout type
    int viewType = position;
    switch (viewType) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_DETAIL: {
            convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.detalle_notification_item_layout, null);

            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.notification_detail_title)).setText(notificacion.getHeader());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.notification_detail_content)).setText(notificacion.getDescription());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.notification_detail_group_name)).setText(notificacion.getGroup());
            break;
        }
        case VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL: {
            convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_lista_notificacion_estudiante, null);

            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.notification_header)).setText(notificacion.getHeader());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.notification_description)).setText(notificacion.getDescription());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.class_notification_header)).setText(notificacion.getGroup());
            break;
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Este es el error que genera:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.julian.notifikame, PID: 12741
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getImportantForAccessibility()' on a null object reference
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java)
                  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java)
                  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java)
                  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java)
                  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
                  at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
```

Alguien me puede ayudar? o por lo menos guiarme? Gracias.

Comment: Mejor utilizar un recyclerview y despues filtrar con el ViewType si es un tipo o otro. Aquí un pequeño ejemplo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530685/is-there-an-addheaderview-equivalent-for-recyclerview/26573338#26573338

Comment: Gracias, pero el recyclerView se puede reemplazar por un fragmento?

Comment: Lo defines en un layout y lo cargas en un fragment y listo, google ha sacado recyclerview para remplazar a los listviews, el recyclerview es más optimizado en mostrar los items en pantalla, personalización etc..